# Java JCE Security Error on Desknow Application

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

DeskNow did not start correctly because of the following error:

Following is the full stack trace of the error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.(JceSecurityManager.java:65)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(Cipher.java:2543)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(Cipher.java:2567)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:548)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:527)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:194)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:350)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getDefaultCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:301)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.initServer(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:162)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:114)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:79)
    at com.ventia.mail.c.k.(k.java:1)
    at com.ventia.mail.c.s.(s.java:24)
    at com.ventia.freedom.k.d.init(d.java:421)
    at com.ventia.freedom.k.d$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c3ccb642.CGLIB$init$46()
    at com.ventia.freedom.k.d$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c3ccb642$$FastClassByCGLIB$$9058e013.invoke()
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:167)
    at com.ventia.freedom.n.s.intercept(s.java:6)
    at com.ventia.freedom.k.d$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c3ccb642.init()
    at com.ventia.freedom.n.w.a(w.java:156)
    at com.ventia.freedom.n.w.i(w.java:415)
    at com.ventia.freedom.g.b$0.run(b$0.java:3)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.(JceSecurity.java:89)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by a trusted signer!
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyPolicySigned(JarVerifier.java:289)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.loadPolicies(JceSecurity.java:316)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:261)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(JceSecurity.java:48)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:81)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.(JceSecurity.java:78)
    ... 23 more

The error occurred at Thu May 22 11:12:03 MYT 2014

DeskNow needs to be restarted.
```

If I install it on Windows, I'm getting a null pointer exception.  What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download JCE zip file from Oracle download site according to your jdk version. It will come with 2 jars of `local_policy.jar` & `US_export_policy.jar`, and `README.txt` file. You need to follow instructions from README file, in fact need **Installation** section.